# How to wrap widgets inside a Column/Row to avoid yellow/black overflow line?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, widget

This is my code(The complete project code : https://github.com/mitchkoko/responsivedesign):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyDesktopBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyDesktopBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[200],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('D E S K T O P'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            // First column
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  // youtube video
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.deepPurple[400],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  // comment section & recommended videos
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 8,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.deepPurple[300],
                            height: 120,
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),

            // second column
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                width: 200,
                color: Colors.deepPurple[300],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I extend the window size I get the following error:

> ═╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY
> ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The
> following assertion was thrown during layout: A RenderFlex overflowed
> by 19 pixels on the bottom. The relevant error-causing widget was:
> Column
> Column:file:///C:/Users/A/Documents/Bandicam/codes/responsivedesign/lib/responsive/desktop_body.dart:20:22
> lib\responsive\desktop_body.dart:20 To inspect this widget in Flutter
> DevTools, visit:
> http://127.0.0.1:9104/#/inspector?uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A3204%2FHgeC4zFKEKs%3D&inspectorRef=inspector-0
> The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical. The
> edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the
> rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually
> caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex. Consider
> applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the
> children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead
> of being sized to their natural size. This is considered an error
> condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
> seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space,
> consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the
> flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a
> ListView. The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#84a04
> relayoutBoundary=up7 OVERFLOWING:   needs compositing   creator:
> Column ← Expanded ← Row ← Padding ← _BodyBuilder ← MediaQuery ←
> LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ← AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ←
> AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ← _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#34509 ink renderer] ← ⋯   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1;
> fit=FlexFit.tight (can use size)   constraints:
> BoxConstraints(w=1173.6, 0.0<=h<=648.0)   size: Size(1173.6, 648.0)
> direction: vertical   mainAxisAlignment: start   mainAxisSize: max
> crossAxisAlignment: center   verticalDirection: down

I know the problem causes because of the following Expanded widget, because the error will be gone by removing it:

```
Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 8,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.deepPurple[300],
          height: 120,
        ),
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue using `aspectRatio: 16 / 9,`. When screen width get bigger and it maintains the aspect ratio it cause overflow.

You can wrap with `ConstrainedBox` and provide `maxHeight` by minimizing padding

```dart
class MyDesktopBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyDesktopBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[200],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('D E S K T O P'),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              // First column
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    // youtube video
                    ConstrainedBox(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(
                        maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight - 16,
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: AspectRatio(
                          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.deepPurple[400],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    // comment section & recommended videos
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: 8,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.deepPurple[300],
                              height: 120,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              // second column
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  width: 200,
                  color: Colors.deepPurple[300],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An expanded widget was added inside the column so till when it had space it was not throwing an error. When you expanded the screen aspect ratio widget grew by size pushing the items below outside the screen and hence the error. You can use this layout instead

```dart
return Scaffold(
  child: Row(
   children: [
     Flexible(
      child: SingleChildScrollView (
       child: Column(
        mainAxisSize : MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Container(
            constrain : BoxConstrain(
              maxHeight : 600,
            ),
           child: AspectRatio(),
          ),
         //Other widgets
        ]
       )
      )
     ),
     SizedBox(
       width: 200,
       child: ListView.builder()
     )
   ]
  )
);
```

Here both sections are individually scrollable. And it doesnt theow an overflow error

Answer (score 0):

You can also this way : wrap second `Column` with Expanded and give it `flex` and also give flex to first `Column` as well.

Here is the code:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class MyDesktopBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyDesktopBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return  Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[200],
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('D E S K T O P'),
  ),
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        // First column
        Expanded(
          flex:3,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              // youtube video
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.deepPurple[400],
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              // comment section & recommended videos
              Flexible(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 8,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.deepPurple[300],
                        height: 120,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),

        // second column
        Expanded(
          flex:1,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.deepPurple[300],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Output : [image]

[image]

[image]

Edited : [image]

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't work and still the same error!

Comment: If you decrease the height of the Chrome window you will see the yellow/black line at the bottom.

Comment: @GoodMan  : Updated my answer. You can check again. thanks

Comment: Thank you but in the new code you have removed the AspectRatio widget that I wanted to keep it as well. Actually the real problem is how to make this code work as expected with AspectRatio.